# выполнить синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

История души человеческой, хотя бы самой мелкой души, едва ли не любопытнее и не полезнее истории целого народа, особенно когда она — следствие наблюдений ума зрелого над самим собою и когда она писана без тщеславного желания возбудить участие или удивление.